# Pyspark dropDuplicates and drop_duplicates()

Tags: python, function, pyspark

I have a data frame of only one column in pyspark, CUSTOMER_ID with repeated values. I want to drop duplicates.

It is a huge dataset, and I have used df.drop_duplicates() which worked. A colleague of mine pointed out that it might be wrong since the function is dropDuplicates in pyspark. The code however ran without any error. Is drop_duplicates() correct, has this function been added to pyspark?

Comment: `drop_duplicates()` is an alias of `dropDuplicates()`. there is another function which does similar thing -- `distinct()`. refer the [function doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pyspark-sql-dataframe-drop-duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pyspark pandas dataframe, then drop_duplicates will work.
Else if you are using simply pyspark dataframe, then dropDuplicates will work.

Ref Link - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropDuplicates.html